# how can i use br in a string to show my string correctly with the html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, string, replace

my string is:

```
$scope.lyrics = 'blablablalba\nblablabla\nblablabla';
```

then i replace `'\n'` to `<br>` tag

and my string now is:

```
$scope.lyrics = 'blablablalba<br>blablabla<br>blablabla';
```

and when my string in html:

```
<p> {{ lyrics }} </p>
```

my result is

```
blablablalba <br> blablabla <br> blablabla
```

what can i do for my result be:

```
lablablalba 

blablabla 

blablabla
```

Comment: have you tried with a coule od <br /><br /> instead of one only?

Comment: I'm guessing Angular's escaping/sanitising the tags.

Comment: yes, the result is the same

Comment: Look into using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sanitize the HTML tags.

```
$scope.lyrics = 'blablablalba<br>blablabla<br>blablabla';

<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="lyrics">
```

The output would be:

```
blablablalba
blablabla
blablabla
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/7670/

Answer (score 1):

Angular inserts strings as text for security and you need to specify to safely allow bypassing sterile content.

[Angular Docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

> ngBindHtml
>   - directive in module ng
>
> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the
>   element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will
>   be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this
>   functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available,

**WORKING EXAMPLE:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.lyrics = 'blablablalba<br>blablabla<br>blablabla';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize/master/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="lyrics"></p>
</body>

</html>
```